# need help sorting my array using bubble method because my text box to show the sorted numbers only show 0

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, random, bubble-sort

I created an array that takes in random numbers when you click the button and that is all working. then i have a button to sort the numbers using bubble sort and show it in a other `textbox`, but when I click the sort button, all i get is repeated 0's. I need help fixing my error please.

```
namespace RandomArray
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within    a       Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class Arraytwenty : Page
    {
        public Arraytwenty()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
        int[] arraytwenty = new int[20];
        public void GenArray20_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int[] arraytwenty = new int[20];
            Random Number = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                int randomnum = Number.Next(1, 101);
                arraytwenty[i] = randomnum;

                Original20Array.Text = Original20Array.Text + " " + Convert.ToString(arraytwenty[i]);
            }




        }

        private void bubsortbtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int temp = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < arraytwenty.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < arraytwenty.Length - 1; j++)
                {
                    if (arraytwenty[j] > arraytwenty[j + 1])
                    {
                        temp = arraytwenty[j + 1];
                        arraytwenty[j + 1] = arraytwenty[j];
                        arraytwenty[j] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
            string value = " ";
            for (int i = 0; i < arraytwenty.Length; i++)
            {
                value += arraytwenty[i].ToString() + " ";


            }

            bubblesortTextbox.Text = value;

        }

        private void clrArraytwenty_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Original20Array.Text = String.Empty;
            bubblesortTextbox.Text = String.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you have a class variable named arraytwenty and a local variable in GenArray20_Click named arraytwenty?? Try removing the int[] arraytwenty = new int[20]; in public void GenArray20_Click()

Comment: yes. any improvements i can make in my code will be appreciated

Comment: That is the problem, the local variable in GenArray20_Click is local to that method, it loses scope after GenArray20_Click returns. You should be populating your class array inside GenArray20_Click as that has scope inside your sort. Please see answer below.

Comment: thanks guys. i appreciate it. still new to all this coding.

Comment: Is C# the first programming language you have worked with?

Comment: yeah it is. started about a month ago

Comment: you have a book to read through and help you learn or have you just been reading things online?

Comment: i am in a college studying it, but yeah not getting alot of help or instructions. The guy who teaches us, moves to fast through the work. still looking for a good book to help me on this

Comment: Love how that works, you pay for an education but the teacher's don't take the time to teach you anything. Must be nice to be a college prof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the same name for variables, it can cause unintended behavior as you have found out:

```
namespace RandomArray
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within    a       Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class Arraytwenty : Page
    {
        //Declare your class array for storing integers, this will have scope in any method of your class
        private int[] arraytwenty;

        public Arraytwenty()
        {
            //initialize your array
            this.arraytwenty = new int[20];
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void GenArray20_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Don't create a local array when you want to use it in your other class methods
            //int[] arraytwenty = new int[20];
            Random Number = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                int randomnum = Number.Next(1, 101);
                arraytwenty[i] = randomnum;

                Original20Array.Text = Original20Array.Text + " " + Convert.ToString(arraytwenty[i]);
            }




        }

        private void bubsortbtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int temp = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < arraytwenty.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < arraytwenty.Length - 1; j++)
                {
                    if (arraytwenty[j] > arraytwenty[j + 1])
                    {
                        temp = arraytwenty[j + 1];
                        arraytwenty[j + 1] = arraytwenty[j];
                        arraytwenty[j] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
            string value = " ";
            for (int i = 0; i < arraytwenty.Length; i++)
            {
                value += arraytwenty[i].ToString() + " ";


            }

            bubblesortTextbox.Text = value;

        }

        private void clrArraytwenty_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Original20Array.Text = String.Empty;
            bubblesortTextbox.Text = String.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have local initlization of array inside GenArray20_Click so it was using local copy to populate Data

Please try this updated code.

**Please Update this Part**

```
    public void GenArray20_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // You have local initilization of array
        // so code inside this method will load data into this array instead of global
        //int[] arraytwenty = new int[20];
        Random Number = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            int randomnum = Number.Next(1, 101);
            arraytwenty[i] = randomnum;

            Original20Array.Text = Original20Array.Text + " " + Convert.ToString(arraytwenty[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please read [answer]. There's absolutely no point to copy the entire unchanged code, making your answer uselessly long

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Done and thanks for pointing it out.!